# Eseper event timeout

Tags: timeout, esper

I want to timeout events individually for each incoming event in esper. How to achieve that? 
If i use time or batch windows, it will wait for other events to first fill the window ,only then the events are moved to rstream.

Answer (score 1):

Use a named window with keep-all and put the condition when events get deleted into an on-delete.

```
create window CustomExpiryWindow.win:keepall() as MyEvent
insert into CustomExpiryWindow select * from MyEvent
on <.......> delete from CustomExpiryWindow where <......>
```

In Alternative there is an extension API for data windows where you could write code to keep and expire events.